# HMAC SHA256 hex digest of a string in Erlang, how?

Tags: erlang, cryptography, sha256, hmac, sha

I am trying to interact with third party real time Web messaging System created and maintained by **[Pusher.com](http://pusher.com/)**. Now, i cannot send anything through the API unless i produce an `HMAC SHA256 hex digest` of my data. A sample source code written in `ruby` could try to illustrate this:

```
# Dependencies
# gem install ruby-hmac
#
require 'rubygems'
require 'hmac-sha2'

secret = '7ad3773142a6692b25b8'
string_to_sign = "POST\n/apps/3/channels/test_channel/events\nauth_key=278d425bdf160c739803&auth_timestamp=1272044395&auth_version=1.0&body_md5=7b3d404f5cde4a0b9b8fb4789a0098cb&name=foo"

hmac = HMAC::SHA256.hexdigest(secret, string_to_sign)

puts hmac
# >> 309fc4be20f04e53e011b00744642d3fe66c2c7c5686f35ed6cd2af6f202e445
```

I checked the **[erlang crypto Library](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/crypto/index.html)** and i cannot even generate a `SHA256 hex digest` "directly"
**How do i do this whole thing in Erlang ?**  help....

***** UPDATE ***** 
I have found solutions here: [[sha256 encryption in erlang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/955161/sha256-encryption-in-erlang)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/955161/sha256-encryption-in-erlang) and they have led me to **[erlsha2](https://github.com/vinoski/erlsha2)**. But still, how do i generate the `HMAC` of a `SHA256 hexdigest` output from this module ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With [erlsha2](https://github.com/vinoski/erlsha2), use the following to get the equivalent of your Ruby code:

```
1> hmac:hexlify(hmac:hmac256(<<"7ad3773142a6692b25b8">>, <<"POST\n/apps/3/channels/test_channel/events\nauth_key=278d425bdf160c739803&auth_timestamp=1272044395&auth_version=1.0&body_md5=7b3d404f5cde4a0b9b8fb4789a0098cb&name=foo">>)).
"309FC4BE20F04E53E011B00744642D3FE66C2C7C5686F35ED6CD2AF6F202E445"
```

Comment: Great! Great ! Great ! Thanks so much @Steve+Vinoski

Answer (score 6):

I just stumbled through this myself and finally managed it just using crypto, so thought I would share. For your usage I think you would want:

`:crypto.hmac(:sha256, secret, string_to_sign) |> Base.encode16`

The hmac portion should take care of digest + hmac and then piping to encode 16 should provide the hex part. I imagine you probably moved on some time ago, but since I just had the same issue and wanted to try and figure it out in stdlib stuff I thought I would share.

Answer (score 3):

The same project (erlsha2) has a module for this:

https://github.com/vinoski/erlsha2/blob/master/src/hmac.erl

Comment: i have looked at this, but i need sample source producing the same results as the ruby code above. Thanks @gleber

Answer (score 2):

If you're using **Elixir**, you can use

```
:crypto.hash(:sha256, [secret, string_to_sign]) 
|> Base.encode16 
|> String.downcase
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a one-liner (Erlang 24):

```erl
[begin if N < 10 -> 48 + N; true -> 87 + N end end ||
            <<N:4>> <= crypto:mac(hmac, sha256, Secret1, StringToSign1)].

>>> "309fc4be20f04e53e011b00744642d3fe66c2c7c5686f35ed6cd2af6f202e445"
```

No need for external libs.